# What is the unit of NSPoint, CGPoint, NSSize, CGSize and NSRect, CGRect?

Tags: uiview, nsview, units-of-measurement, nsrect, nspoint

What is the unit of CGPoint, CGSize and CGRect ; NSSize, NSPoint and NSRect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unit of `CGPoint`, etc. is `point`. A point represents a pixel on non-retina screens and two pixels on retina screens.